# Display posts having custom field value equal to an array of values - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have an array of city names

```
$cities = array('Ludhiana','Doraha','Jagraon','Moga','Phillaur','Ahmedgarh');
```

In my wordpress implementation, I have a custom-field named 'cty_name'

Now, I want to query those posts which contains any array value in the 'cty_name' custom field. I know this could be done using meta_query in Wp_Query function, but could not figure this out.

Please lead me to a fast and efficient way to get these posts, actually I would be having  approximately 100 values in the array, and that would be inefficient to compare each value with the posts.

Thank You,

**EDIT :**

I solved the Problem, it was an easy one though...  Thanx all for your kind support

```
$cities = array('Ludhiana','Doraha','Jagraon','Moga','Phillaur','Ahmedgarh');

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'city_posts',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'cty_name',
        'value' => $cities,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the Problem, it was an easy one though...  Thanx all for your kind support

```
$cities = array('Ludhiana','Doraha','Jagraon','Moga','Phillaur','Ahmedgarh');

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'city_posts',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'cty_name',
        'value' => $cities,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for size with `wp_query`, im going to infer that your key is `cty_name`:

```
$args = ( 'meta_key' => 'cty_name'); // this will get all posts with meta key cty_name
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    the_content();
endwhile;


wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I think, I was unable to explain the situation in details. The requirement is that, 

if (value of custom field 'cty_name' exists in the given array $cities){
display the post;
}

Comment: is cty_name your meta_key with multiple values? stored to it?

Comment: 'cty_name' is just the name of the custom field,  multiple values to be compared are stored in $cities array..

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this one

```
<?php $punjab= array ('Ludhiana','Doraha','Jagraon','Moga','Phillaur','Ahmedgarh'); print_r($punjab); $pos = array_search('Ludhiana', $punjab); echo 'Phillaur found at: '.$pos; ?>
```

Comment: thank you..  but you just gave an opposite solution..
I want to display all the posts which contain any of the array values (ludhiana, doraha, jagraon.....  & all) in a custom field.

Comment: now  you get the  searched value from array  put the if condition and match the  searced result value to  your custom field value if value matches then show the   post  other wise not

Comment: but that would be extremely inefficient at runtime, because i have approx 100 values in the array and thousands of posts to be matched with...

Comment: Ok, let me check its efficiency / time taken as I want this to make it as fast possible considering the level of project implementation.
Thanks for your support...